# EventSetter for Slider Control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tried to write an EventSetter for 4 slide controls but it doesn't work.
Keeps giving me error i.e. 'FourthProject.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'slider_ValueChanged' and no extension method 'slider_ValueChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'FourthProject.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is what I tried:

```
<EventSetter Event="Slider.ValueChanged"
Handler="slider_ValueChanged" />
```

Here is the code behind

private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidColorBrush backgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush();
            backgroundColor.Color = Color.FromArgb((byte)alphaSlider.Value
     (byte)redSlider.Value, (byte)greenSlider.Value, (byte)blueSlider.Value);

```
        // set colorLabel's background to new color
        colorLabel.Background = backgroundColor;
    }
```

Please help I am new to WPF and its quite confusing. Thanks

Comment: thats probably beacuse you dont have a eventhandler in the code behind

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work either. I thought the IDE would automatically generate the eventhandler

Comment: Why dont you post you code behind?

Answer (score 1):

XAML is just fine:

```
<EventSetter Event="Slider.ValueChanged" Handler="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
```

You just need to properly define your handler (code behind):

```
public void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value Changed: " + e.NewValue.ToString());
}
```

Maybe you have a DataContext set on your root element or your event handler isn't public.